# Tkinter: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind_all'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tkinter, pandastable

I'm using pandastable to implement a pandas dataframe into my tkinter window however, an error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind_all'

Keeps coming up when I use this line:

```
table = pt = Table(window, dataframe=stats)
```

full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel

places = {"Place":['1st'], "Name":['Derik'], "Time":['1.89']}
window = tk.Tk()

stats = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(places)
table = Table(window, dataframe=stats)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `pandastable` wants you to put the widget inside a container and not a window. You can find this out by checking the [line 88](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/blob/master/pandastable/core.py#L88) and [line 264](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/blob/master/pandastable/core.py#L264) of the [`pandastable` source code](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/blob/master/pandastable/core.py):

```
class Table(Canvas):
    ...
    def __init__(self, parent=None, model=None, dataframe=None, ...):

        self.parentframe = parent # Line 88

        ...

    def doBindings(self):
        ...
        self.parentframe.master.bind_all("<KP_8>", self.handle_arrow_keys) # Line 264
```

As you can see, `self.parentframe` is the parent you pass in, in your case, `window`. And in line 264, they access the `master` of the `self.parentframe`, which is `None` because root windows don't have masters. But other widgets like frames do.

So all you have to do is, put this widget inside a container like `Frame`:

```
frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

table = Table(frame, dataframe=stats)
table.show()
```